# PHPUnit SYSPATH not defined in file under test

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpunit

I have a PHP project. There is a class My_Class that I need to test. I created a test class in the same package.

```
<?php
require_once 'myclass.php';
class My_ClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function test()
    {
        My_Class::doSomething(1);
    }
}
```

File `myclass.php` starts with this line

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No Direct Script Access.');
```

When I run the test I get `No Direct Script Access.` message. I checked to make sure that it is the same message from `myclass.php` file.

How should I define or include `SYSPATH` so I could run my unit test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Create `bootstrap.php` file for the unit tests and define the `SYSPATH` like this `define('SYSPATH', realpath($system).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);`.